# Can't access svn repository via SVN:// protocol, only via file:// on Synology

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, synology

I'm trying to set up SVN on a Synology NAS drive and it seems to be working correctly BUT I can only seem to access the repositories via the `file://` protocol rather that `svn://`.

I have followed the instructions here but no joy. It looks like `svnserve` should be running but it doesn't seem to be responding to requests (I've tried with CLI and with TortoiseSVN).

http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_Subversion

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you connect via telnet? telnet <servername> <port>

Answer (score 0):

Check, that port 3690 is accessible from you computer. Easiest way to do it via program pingtcp.
Which version of DSM and SVN package do you use?